# JQuery templates are not working with arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am just learning Jquery templates and trying different things step by step. Now I tried it with single entry data element and it works fine. As far as I understand If I replace data with data array then it will show all the elements without using {each} tag. But in this case it is just erroring out. in Jquery. saying `k.nodes is undefined`.

Here is a small code snippet:

```
// my binding
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.tmpl("<div class = 'Test'>${Name}<div>", movies)
    .appendTo('#EmployeeContainer');
  $('#Template')
    .tmpl(movies)
    .appendTo('#EmployeeContainer');
});

// my data
var movies = [
  { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
  { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
  { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
];

// part of my template from where Release year is coming
<script id = "Template" type ="text/templating">
  <div class = 'Test'>${ReleaseYear}<div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may have forgotten to compile the template.

Take a look at the first example [at jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/).

Specifically, you need to call: `$.template(...);` to compile the template.

You've already got the `$.tmpl(...);` part which renders the template. But, you need to compile it before rendering.

**Update:** The main thing that was wrong is that you are missing the closing div in your template. You have `<div>` instead of `</div>` here's an updated [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PcFC/4/). Also, remember this is a plugin, so you need to [download](https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.js) the [plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl).

Comment: Well, I went through the entrire tutorial and it says that we do not need to do any extra coding. Just need to replace the data with data array and template will generate the template for each element... i am not sure why it is not working............

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to call `$.template(...)` on the template before calling `$.tmpl(...)` if you're still having problems can you update your question with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Here is the code with compiled template. still not working but it works with non-Array elemnt. By the way seems like fiddle does not work properly with Templating code...here is the link   http://jsfiddle.net/7PcFC/2/

Comment: If you replace Movies with movie(singular), which is a non array object it works fine  with me.

Comment: Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/7PcFC/4/ The main thing you were doing wrong is in your Template, you put <div> at the end of the template. Notice after ${ReleaseYear} you put <div> with that as an opening div instead of the close div as it should be, it was breaking.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, had I been more observant, I could had caught it. But thank you so much for your help that was very very helpful:)

Comment: By the way, as a side note. You don't have to compile it when it is a data array. I just updated the Fiddle for you to take a look at:http://jsfiddle.net/7PcFC/8/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I came across this same issue recently.  I tried jsfiddle.net/7PcFC/8/ as mentioned above, and had the following results in these browsers:

Firefox 29: WORKS

Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m: DOES NOT WORK

IE 9.0.8112.16421: DOES NOT WORK

For Chrome and IE, it just displays "Hello"